# Yii Return Attributes of Joined Models

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii-cmodel

In Yii, I have media which is tied to a location; I have the relations set up as so:

public function relations() {

```
    return array(
        'users' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Users', array('id' => 'user_id')), 
        'locations' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Locations', array('id' => 'object_id'), 'together' => true, 'select' => '*')
    );
}
```

When I query, I use the 'with' statement to join the tables.

```
$models = Media::model()->with('lodcation') -> findAll($criteria);
```

And then I am putting the data into a json object and returning it as a CJSON response.

```
echo CJSON::encode($models);
```

The problem is the fields that are being returned are only from the parent model, which is Media, and not the joined model, Locations. My question is how can I display both the parent model and joined model results in Yii?

Comment: what does `var_dump($models[0]->locations);` return? (assuming `with('lodcation')` is a typo in your question and you mean `with('locations')` ;))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CJSON::encode()` will always only use the direct the attributes from the parent model. You could try one of these extensions instead:

- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/carjson
- http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/ejsonbehavior

Answer (score 2):

Your relationship

```
'locations' => array(self::HAS_ONE, 'Locations', array('id' => 'object_id'), 'together' => true, 'select' => '*')
```

Has the name `'locations'`, but when you try to use it in your query you refer to `->with('lodcation')`, which is making the findAll method trying to eagerly load data from an unexisting relation. Changing your call to `$models = Media::model()->with('locations') -> findAll($criteria);`
should correct this problem.

Maybe the relationship name you're using is making some noise here: `'locations'` as a plural seems to be referring to an array of locations. Keeping this name in single `'location'` should make the meaning of the `self::HAS_ONE` relationship clearer.